# Fill empty rows with data from previous days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table looks like:

| date | block_date | installs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-10 | 355 |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-11 | 20 |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-12 | 70 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-13 | 150 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-14 | 120 |

I want to copy data from `previous` days and fill `current` day:

| date | block_date | installs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-11 | 20 |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-12 | 70 |
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-10 | 355 |

As a result I want to see this table:

| date | block_date | installs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-10 | 355 |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-10 | 355 |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-11 | 20 |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-12 | 70 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-10 | 355 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-11 | 20 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-12 | 70 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-13 | 150 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-14 | 120 |

I need to take some specific `date` and look at `block_date` and fill it for month ago. For example: for `2022-01-27` it will be block_dates from `2022-01-14` to `2021-12-15` (month gap, no need more). I need to check previous `date` (2022-01-26, 2022-01-25, 2022-01-24, etc) to fill it if it's empty. I don't have ideas how to handle this and I hope, I described that not that terrible.

Is it possible? I can describe it like:

```
SELECT installs FROM table
WHERE date = '2022-01-27' and block_date = '2022-01-13'
IF block_date EXIST THEN USE THIS
IF block_date = '2022-01-13' NOT EXIST THEN 
SELECT installs WHERE date '2021-01-26' and block_date = '2022-01-13'
AND PUT installs FROM date '2021-01-26' and block_date = '2022-01-13' TO NEW ROW as date '2021-01-27' and block_date = '2022-01-13'
```

I need to check 30 previous days (month gap from block_date) from each `block_date` and fill it.

Comment: I have not understood what you want... From this sentence: "I need to take some specific date and look at block_date and fill it for month ago." What operation is "take"? a SELECT? what do you mean with specific `date`? a `WHERE date = ...`? What is "fill it"? I do not see any empty value to "fill"; finally, what is "month ago"? `date - 1 month`? `block_date - 1 month`? In a well described question, I would not have that many questions just for 1 sentence, not to mention the rest... Please edit it with what you have so far and what is missing.

Comment: Tried to describe it in `sql` like query

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation still is not completely clear.

I expect your query to be something close to:

```
WITH Selection AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
('2022-01-25'::date,'2022-01-10'::date,355),
('2022-01-26'::date,'2022-01-11'::date,20),
('2022-01-26'::date,'2022-01-12'::date,70),
('2022-01-27'::date,'2022-01-13'::date,150),
('2022-01-27'::date,'2022-01-14'::date,120)
) MyTable(date,block_date,installs)
WHERE block_date = '2022-01-13'
AND '2022-01-27' BETWEEN date - '1 month'::interval AND date
)
SELECT generate_series(COALESCE(previous_date, date-1)::timestamp, (date-1)::timestamp, '1 day')::date, block_date, installs
FROM (
    SELECT *, LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS previous_date
    FROM Selection
) T
```

The 1 month limit has been placed in the `Selection` CTE.
The `LEAD` window function is in charge of getting the previous value of `date` while generate_series will return a set of up to 1 month worth of data.

Try it, see if it works for you and if not, comment with the reason why it does  not.